# Identifying the Slow Down for Matrix Multiplication Algorithms

Tags: c++, c, algorithm, performance, matrix-multiplication

First, I understand that the are many algorithms for matrix multiplication. For this question, I will be considering the following:

Algorithm A:

```
for(i = 0; i < N; i++)
{
    for(j = 0; j < N; j++)
    {
        prod[i][j] = 0;
            for(k = 0; k < N; k++)
                prod[i][j] += mat1[i][k] * mat2[k][j]
    }
}
```

Algorithm B:

```
for(i = 0; i < N; i++)
{
    for(j = 0; j < N; j++)
    {
        temp = 0;
            for(k = 0; k < N; k++)
                temp += mat1[i][k] * mat2[k][j]
        prod[i][j] = temp;
    }
}
```

A coworker and I both agree that algorithm `B` outperforms (faster run times than) algorithm `A`. However, we both have different reasoning for why `B` performs better.

The first theory is that because we replace `C[i][j]` inside the inner most loop, we perform N<sup>3</sup> less pointer arithmetic operations, thus causing our improvement.

The second theory is that because we replace `C[i][j]` inside the inner most loop, we perform N<sup>3</sup> less memory accesses, thus causing our improvement.

The question is:

How do I set up an experiment to isolate each of these factors to decide empirically which, if either, have the larger affect on run time?

Comment: shouldn't it be `+=` ? -> `temp += ...`

Comment: uhm, neither seems to be correct, in the first place... you meant += in bothcases where you currently just assign =, right?

Comment: Depends on what `mat1`, `mat2` and `prod` is. If the compiler can't know that they point to different memory areas, it must assume that the assignment overwrite the source operands. That's different for `temp`, if that's a local.

Comment: You're both correct, it has been edited.

Comment: Every c++ Compiler I know of has an optimizer good enough to turn these two into the same run-time code anyway, so ...